# Adjacency matrix for polygons using Java

Tags: polygon, java, eclipse, adjacency

I am trying to create an adjacency matrix from a set of polygons. That is, I have a bunch of polygons and I want to identify which polygons have a common edge or "touch" each other. Once I find this information, I want to create an n x n matrix that indicates whether those each polygon either touches or does not touch the other polygon. Something like this:

```
      Poly1    Poly2   Poly3
Poly1   0        1       0
Poly2   1        0       1
Poly3   0        1       0
```

That is the goal anyway. I was wondering if anyone knew of a Java package or such that could help me do this. I read some posts on doing this using VBA but I am wondering if Java Eclipse can be used for this purpose because I need to implement the adjacency matrix in a bigger program that I am writing on Java.

Edit:
I have the polygon as a shapefile drawing. I think triangular Matrix will be fine because of the symmetry.